# Error in XML Error Domain=NSXMLParserErrorDomain Code=39?

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparsererrordomain

I have following xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<businesses>
<business>
<businessCount>1</businessCount>
<dealsCount>3</dealsCount>
<city>asdf</city>
<state>asdf</state>
<country>akdsjfasdf</country>
<latitude></latitude>
<longitude></longitude>
</business>

<business>
<businessCount>1</businessCount>
<dealsCount>1</dealsCount>
<city>karachi</city>
<state>sindg</state>
<country>Pakistan</country>
<latitude>24.8567436</latitude>
<longitude>66.8734836</longitude>
</business>

<business>
<businessCount>1</businessCount>
<dealsCount>2</dealsCount>
<city>karachi</city>
<state>sindh</state>
<country>pakistan</country>
<latitude>24.893379</latitude>
<longitude>67.028061</longitude>
</business>
</businesses>
```

but getting the following error while parsing

```
    Error Domain=NSXMLParserErrorDomain Code=39 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 39.)"
```

I read the documentation and also varify the syntax of XML, but didn't find what issue is with it.

Can anyone give any idea or help?

Comment: xml is fine i think problem is in your parsing code

Comment: how, I am writting the file, data returns, then same xml parsing working with one url, but with second url it doesn't Ron

Comment: this error is coming when network is slow

Comment: this error comes when "NSXMLParserAttributeNotStartedError = 39"

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava, ya, this is error

Answer (score 3):

check these error code in apple documentation

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html

````
 enum {
       NSXMLParserInternalError = 1,
       NSXMLParserOutOfMemoryError = 2,
       NSXMLParserDocumentStartError = 3,
       NSXMLParserEmptyDocumentError = 4,
       NSXMLParserPrematureDocumentEndError = 5,
       NSXMLParserInvalidHexCharacterRefError = 6,
       NSXMLParserInvalidDecimalCharacterRefError = 7,
       NSXMLParserInvalidCharacterRefError = 8,
       NSXMLParserInvalidCharacterError = 9,
       NSXMLParserCharacterRefAtEOFError = 10,
       NSXMLParserCharacterRefInPrologError = 11,
       NSXMLParserCharacterRefInEpilogError = 12,
       NSXMLParserCharacterRefInDTDError = 13,
       NSXMLParserEntityRefAtEOFError = 14,
       NSXMLParserEntityRefInPrologError = 15,
       NSXMLParserEntityRefInEpilogError = 16,
       NSXMLParserEntityRefInDTDError = 17,
       NSXMLParserParsedEntityRefAtEOFError = 18,
       NSXMLParserParsedEntityRefInPrologError = 19,
       NSXMLParserParsedEntityRefInEpilogError = 20,
       NSXMLParserParsedEntityRefInInternalSubsetError = 21,
       NSXMLParserEntityReferenceWithoutNameError = 22,
       NSXMLParserEntityReferenceMissingSemiError = 23,
       NSXMLParserParsedEntityRefNoNameError = 24,
       NSXMLParserParsedEntityRefMissingSemiError = 25,
       NSXMLParserUndeclaredEntityError = 26,
       NSXMLParserUnparsedEntityError = 28,
       NSXMLParserEntityIsExternalError = 29,
       NSXMLParserEntityIsParameterError = 30,
       NSXMLParserUnknownEncodingError = 31,
       NSXMLParserEncodingNotSupportedError = 32,
       NSXMLParserStringNotStartedError = 33,
       NSXMLParserStringNotClosedError = 34,
       NSXMLParserNamespaceDeclarationError = 35,
       NSXMLParserEntityNotStartedError = 36,
       NSXMLParserEntityNotFinishedError = 37,
       NSXMLParserLessThanSymbolInAttributeError = 38,
       NSXMLParserAttributeNotStartedError = 39,
       NSXMLParserAttributeNotFinishedError = 40,
       NSXMLParserAttributeHasNoValueError = 41,
       NSXMLParserAttributeRedefinedError = 42,
       NSXMLParserLiteralNotStartedError = 43,
       NSXMLParserLiteralNotFinishedError = 44,
       NSXMLParserCommentNotFinishedError = 45,
       NSXMLParserProcessingInstructionNotStartedError = 46,
       NSXMLParserProcessingInstructionNotFinishedError = 47,
       NSXMLParserNotationNotStartedError = 48,
       NSXMLParserNotationNotFinishedError = 49,
       NSXMLParserAttributeListNotStartedError = 50,
       NSXMLParserAttributeListNotFinishedError = 51,
       NSXMLParserMixedContentDeclNotStartedError = 52,
       NSXMLParserMixedContentDeclNotFinishedError = 53,
       NSXMLParserElementContentDeclNotStartedError = 54,
       NSXMLParserElementContentDeclNotFinishedError = 55,
       NSXMLParserXMLDeclNotStartedError = 56,
       NSXMLParserXMLDeclNotFinishedError = 57,
       NSXMLParserConditionalSectionNotStartedError = 58,
       NSXMLParserConditionalSectionNotFinishedError = 59,
       NSXMLParserExternalSubsetNotFinishedError = 60,
       NSXMLParserDOCTYPEDeclNotFinishedError = 61,
       NSXMLParserMisplacedCDATAEndStringError = 62,
       NSXMLParserCDATANotFinishedError = 63,
       NSXMLParserMisplacedXMLDeclarationError = 64,
       NSXMLParserSpaceRequiredError = 65,
       NSXMLParserSeparatorRequiredError = 66,
       NSXMLParserNMTOKENRequiredError = 67,
       NSXMLParserNAMERequiredError = 68,
       NSXMLParserPCDATARequiredError = 69,
       NSXMLParserURIRequiredError = 70,
       NSXMLParserPublicIdentifierRequiredError = 71,
       NSXMLParserLTRequiredError = 72,
       NSXMLParserGTRequiredError = 73,
       NSXMLParserLTSlashRequiredError = 74,
       NSXMLParserEqualExpectedError = 75,
       NSXMLParserTagNameMismatchError = 76,
       NSXMLParserUnfinishedTagError = 77,
       NSXMLParserStandaloneValueError = 78,
       NSXMLParserInvalidEncodingNameError = 79,
       NSXMLParserCommentContainsDoubleHyphenError = 80,
       NSXMLParserInvalidEncodingError = 81,
       NSXMLParserExternalStandaloneEntityError = 82,
       NSXMLParserInvalidConditionalSectionError = 83,
       NSXMLParserEntityValueRequiredError = 84,
       NSXMLParserNotWellBalancedError = 85,
       NSXMLParserExtraContentError = 86,
       NSXMLParserInvalidCharacterInEntityError = 87,
       NSXMLParserParsedEntityRefInInternalError = 88,
       NSXMLParserEntityRefLoopError = 89,
       NSXMLParserEntityBoundaryError = 90,
       NSXMLParserInvalidURIError = 91,
       NSXMLParserURIFragmentError = 92,
       NSXMLParserNoDTDError = 94,
       NSXMLParserDelegateAbortedParseError = 512
    };
    typedef NSInteger NSXMLParserError;```
````

Comment: I wrote that there is no documentation, just expect name of error, cant specify it, see my question, I have already specified

Comment: i already told u this error is coming when network is slow try this one in ur wifi connection

Comment: then how would I know that connection is slower, and alert to user?